# How to diagnose an intermittent Azure Custom Script Extension hang?

Tags: azure

We are using the `Windows-10-N-x64` Azure VM image made available via MSDN for some automation and are intermittently seeing our [Custom Script Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/extensions-customscript?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2fwindows%2ftoc.json) fail to initialize on the VM. It fails approximately **20%** of the time.

When it does hang, `Get-AzureRmVMExtension` doesn't indicate any errors have occurred during the hang.

```
ResourceGroupName       : resource-group-id
VMName                  : Windows-VM
Name                    : Script-Extensions
Location                : centralus
Etag                    : null
Publisher               : Microsoft.Compute
ExtensionType           : CustomScriptExtension
TypeHandlerVersion      : 1.7
Id                      : /subscriptions/subscription-id/resourceGroups/resource-group-id/providers/M
                          icrosoft.Compute/virtualMachines/Windows-VM/extensions/Script-Extensions
PublicSettings          : {
                            "fileUris": [
                              "https://resource-group-id.blob.core.windows.net/provisioning-container/Enable-PSRemotingAnd
                          DSC.ps1",
                              "https://resource-group-id.blob.core.windows.net/provisioning-container/microsoft-windows-ne
                          tfx3-ondemand-package.cab"
                            ],
                            "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File
                          Enable-PSRemotingAndDSC.ps1 -NetFxCabinetFilePath
                          microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package.cab -DNSName
                          dns-name.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com"
                          }
ProtectedSettings       :
ProvisioningState       : Creating
Statuses                :
SubStatuses             :
AutoUpgradeMinorVersion : False
ForceUpdateTag          :
```

The Azure portal will show the Extension state as `Transitioning` during this time with no errors reported.

The logs on the VM in `C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.7` also don't show any errors.

If we take no action, we will eventually receive a timeout error.

```
Exception             : System.Exception: 4:00:34 PM - Resource 
                        Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions 
                        'Windows-VM/Script-Extensions' failed with message '{
                          "status": "Failed",
                          "error": {
                            "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
                            "message": "The resource operation completed with 
                        terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
                            "details": [
                              {
                                "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningTimeout",
                                "message": "Provisioning of VM extension 
                        'Script-Extensions' has timed out. Extension 
                        installation may be taking too long, or extension 
                        status could not be obtained."
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }'
TargetObject          : 
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) 
                        [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implem
                        entation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

If we log on to the VM while it is hanging and manually execute `C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.7\enable.cmd` then the extension will succeed.

At this point, we are wondering if this is an issue with Azure itself as our custom script itself is not even executing. Are there any more logs we could look at to diagnose this hang?

Comment: I would redirect all output to a file and check progress: `Get-Something 2>&1 | Out-File d:\ext.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was confirmed as a bug in the Azure custom script extension by Azure support with an expected resolution date of July 2017.

Comment: Did you get any confirmation from Microsoft that this bug has been resolved? As of 2024 We are still experiencing slow custom scripts executions, with a majority of the time been spent ‘transitioning’

Answer (score -1):

I encountered a similar issue when attempting to deploy a VM with the Custom Script Extension (version 1.9), along with other resources, using an ARM template via the Azure CLI 2.0. The workaround described by the OP of manually executing `enable.cmd` did not have any effect, and for me the issue was occurring 100% of the time.

Here is the CustomScriptExtension portion of my ARM template.

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
    "name": "vm/CustomScriptExtension",
    "location": "westus",
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
        "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.9",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
            "fileUris": [
                "https://myblobsubdomain.blob.core.windows.net/container/my-script.ps1"
            ],
            "commandToExecute": ".\\my-script.ps1"
        }
    }
}
```

Even for a one-line "echo" script, the process was hanging seemingly forever (I never did let it run long enough to see if it would time out), with a status of Transitioning listed for the extension in the Azure portal. I was able to confirm that no part of the script was ever running.

It turned out that the problem was my commandToExecute, specifically my attempting to run the script with `.\my-script.ps1`. Once I changed it to invoke the `powershell` command directly, the issue went away and my script ran successfully!

Here is the final, working version of the relevant portion of my ARM template.

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
    "name": "vm/CustomScriptExtension",
    "location": "westus",
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
        "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.9",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
            "fileUris": [
                "https://myblobsubdomain.blob.core.windows.net/container/my-script.ps1"
            ],
            "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File ./my-script.ps1"
        }
    }
}
```

Note that specifying `-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` is also necessary for the script to actually run, but omitting it does not cause the Transitioning issue.